# Fetch info from a txt file on a server and then put it into in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, url

So I'm making an HWID Spoofer in the form of a batch file, however I want it to be restricted so I'm making a system that verifies the user's baseboard ID. the way I want to do this is have the batch file read a txt file from my server with a list of accepted IDs and then put them into where the ID on the second line is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%A IN ('WMIC baseboard get serialnumber /value ^| FIND /I "SerialNumber="') DO SET serialnumber=%%A
if /i not "%serialnumber%" == "PF0TPMUN" goto :unverified
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I achieved something similar with this:

`for /f %%a in (baseboardid.txt) do (
echo Pinging %%a...
ping %%a
)
pause`

But that only works with a local txt file and I need it to get one from a url.

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Batch files can read from paths that are UNC - **\\servername\share\folder\file** or mapped drive letters - **c:\folder\file**

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have said server, it's a text file hosted on my site. https://staging.shopbattledash.com/resources/baseboardid.txt

Comment: Please copy the sample text of the `baseboardid.txt` file into your question by [edit]ing it rather than posting a comment with an URL because it might later become invalid (you may of course keep the URL in addition)...

Answer (score 0):

After about an hour I just decided to use wget, here's the code:

```
if not exist "baseboardid.txt" wget.exe https://staging.shopbattledash.com/resources/baseboardid.txt
FOR /F %%B IN (baseboardid.txt) DO SET serialurl=%%B
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%A IN ('WMIC baseboard get serialnumber /value ^| FIND /I "SerialNumber="') DO SET serialnumber=%%A
if /i not "%serialnumber%" == "%serialurl%" goto :unverified
del "baseboardid.txt"
```

Comment: `FOR /F %%B IN (baseboardid.txt) DO SET serialurl=%%B` gets you the *first token of the last line* of the text file. Based on the file structure I think you need another approach. (like `findstr /x "%serialnumber%" baseboardid.txt >nul || goto :eof`, which exits, when the string isn't in the file.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going with this code:
`find "%serialnumber%" baseboardid.txt > yourbaseboardid.txt`
 `FOR /F %%B IN (yourbaseboardid.txt) DO SET serialurl=%%B`